# I want to use an array to produce multiple objects with different values

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, processing

so I am really new to programming in general.
Right now I am using processing/Java to do stuff.

Ive got an assignment to program a small video game and I am stuck for a few hours now, kinda frustrated so I decided to try to get help here.

So right now I have made a class called Gesichter where I defined properties and functions.
Now I can draw the Object I created by defining the function in my main program, then running it.

problem is... I want to have this object drawn multiple times but with slightly different heights(yPos). I can do it by hand and just rename and readjust the object, then putting it under the draw function. But I have to do it in a more efficient way for the assignment.
My teacher said it can be done by using an array but I am at this moment just confused what to do and I am not sure at all how to do it.
preferably I would like to have about 20 "Gesichter" with different heights.

Also how do I get to use the whEllipse variable from my class Gesichter in the main program?

Here is the code so far:

```
Gesichter rot;


void settings(){
  size(700,700);
  
}


void setup(){
  
 rot = new Gesichter(random(-whEllipse,height),random(-whEllipse,height));
  
  
}
 
void draw(){
  background(0);
  rot.paint();
  rot.move();
  
}
```

so this is my main.

this is the "Gesichter" class so far.

```
public class Gesichter {


  //Eigenschaften
  float whEllipse= 200;
  float yPos = random(-whEllipse,height);
  float  xPos = random(-whEllipse,height);
  float xSpeed = 4;
  float P = 4;

  Gesichter(float yPos,float  xPos) {
    
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    
    yPos = random(-whEllipse,height);
    xPos = random(-whEllipse/2,width);
    
  }

  //Methoden/Funktionen
  void move() {

    xPos += xSpeed;
    yPos += (P*sin(radians(xPos))+1); //+1 macht dass sich das Gesicht langsam runter bewegt.
    if (xPos>= width+whEllipse/2) {

      // P = P+1; Maybe falls ich größere Amplitude will

      xPos = -whEllipse/2;
    }
    if (yPos >= height+whEllipse/2) {
      yPos = random(-whEllipse, height/2);
      xPos = random(-200, whEllipse/2);
    }
  }
  
  void paint() {

    fill(255, 0, 0);
    circle(xPos, yPos, whEllipse);
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out ://
would be so greatful.

Comment: Check the class; it looks like you posted the main program twice.

Comment: ohh :00 thx for making me aware!

Comment: should be the right one now

Comment: Unfortunately we are not allowed to write your code for you, but we can offer advice.  This video may be helpful to get you started: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGXrIhRopFo&t=4s

Comment: I am unable to run your code as posted.  The error message states 'whEllipse cannot be resolved to a variable'.  It is not defined or initialized  in your main section.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. You'll have to do something similar in your draw() method.

```java
Gesichter[] rots = new Gesichter[20];

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < rots.length; i++) {
    rots[i] = new Gesichter(random(-whEllipse, height), random(-whEllipse, height));
  }
}
```

Regarding your Gesichter constructor: those last two lines are actually useless. You're reassigning the constructor *parameters* to those new values, essentially throwing them away. It should look like this.

```java
  Gesichter(float yPos, float xPos) {
    
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.xPos = xPos;
    
  }
```

Now, I don't know much about German, but... isn't that class a single face? Would Gesicht be more appropriate?

---

Regarding your whEllipse problem: you need to either pass it in from the outside:

```java
  public Gesichter(float yPos, float xPos, float whEllipse) {
    ...
  }
```

```java
void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < rots.length; i++) {
    rots[i] = new Gesichter(random(-200, height), random(-200, height), 200);
  }
}
```

Or make it static and reference it by the class name:

```java
public class Gesichter {
  public static final float WH_ELLIPSE = 200;
  ...
}
```

```java
void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < rots.length; i++) {
    rots[i] = new Gesichter(random(-Gesichter.WH_ELLIPSE, height), random(-Gesichter.WH_ELLIPSE, height));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank's a lot ! this really frustrated me, going to continue based on your advice. You really helped me out :). haha yeah I have to think about the Gesichter stuff too.. going to be easier to solve this problem I think